# What are/is a Trill?

Tags: aliens, star-trek

In Star Trek, we encounter the Trill species. It is unclear, however, if the Trill are the symbiont, or the humanoid species from the planet, or the combination of symbiont and host.

Do we know what specifically a Trill is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The terminology is inconsistent.**

### Many sources say **the Trill are the humanoids**...

... including the (not always reliable) [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Trill):

> The Trill (or Trills) were a humanoid species native to the planet Trill. A small percentage of the Trill population co-existed with a sentient symbiotic organism known as a symbiont inside their bodies. The resulting joined Trills had personalities which were a synthesis of the two beings including the memories, and to some extent the personalities, of the previous hosts of the symbiont. This way, the joined being gained all the skills and occupations of the previous hosts.

More canonically, unjoined Trill such as the [Guardians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Trill_Guardian) are also called Trill several times in DS9. E.g. see the following quote from the DS9 episode [*Equilibrium*](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/450.htm):

> DAX: I don't need therapy, Julian, I need answers. Maybe the Guardians could help me.
>   BASHIR: The Guardians?
>   SISKO: They're unjoined Trill who have devoted their lives to the care of the symbionts.

And also the following quote from the DS9 episode [*Facets*](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/471.htm):

> DAX: The memories are transferred telepathically by a Guardian.
>   ODO: A Guardian?
>   LEETA: They take care of the symbionts. Usually they're unjoined Trill.

### ...  but others say **a Trill is the combination of symbiont and host** ...

The phrase "becoming a Trill" is often used for the ceremony of joining symbiont and host. E.g. see the following quote from the DS9 episode [*Dax*](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/408.htm):

> SISKO: At what age did the host, Jadzia, first want to be joined as a Trill?
>   DAX: I wanted it since I was a child. I worked very hard for it.
>   SISKO: The competition to become a Trill is very strong, then, among potential hosts.
>   DAX: Yes. It's considered a great honour.

And in *The Official Star Trek: Deep Space Nine Magazine*, Vol. 2, p. 56, Terry Farrelly calls the joining ceremony

> a ceremony of honor in which you become a Trill.

### ... and some even suggest that the Trill is the symbiont.

The phrase "become a Trill host" is used in the DS9 episode [*Playing God*](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/437.htm), suggesting that the humanoids are hosts *to the Trill*, the symbionts:

> DAX: Arjin, if you truly want to become a Trill host someday, you'll never call me ma'am again.
>   ARJIN: Yes, Lieutenant.

Comment: You've got several episodes of DS9 to play with for canon sources.  The phrase "unjoined trill" definitely appears in DS9 and clearly (in context) refers to the humanoid and not the symbiont.  OTOH, TNG's introduction of the Trill contradicts DS9 all over the place, so YMMV on which one is "canonical."

Comment: @Kevin Thanks - after you told me the exact phrase to search for, I've now found a canonical quote to edit in.

Comment: @Kevin - Agree. The term 'trill' seems to refer to the joined  humanoid and symbiont or the humanoid alone but never the symbiont. The term 'unjoined trill' obviously refers to the humanoid and the term 'joined trill' obviously refers to the combined humanoid/symbiont.

Comment: The use of "become a Trill" to mean "be joined with a symbiont" also occurs in *Deep Space Nine* at least once: \[[link](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/S411519d73/Star+Trek%3A+Deep+Space+Nine/Dax/become+a+Trill)]. (But the speaker is not a Trill, so may have the terminology a bit wrong.) Likewise "become a Trill host": \[[link](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/S412067346/Star+Trek%3A+Deep+Space+Nine/Playing+God/become+a+Trill+host)] (which *is* a Trill speaking).

Comment: @ruakh Thanks - it seems the answer is even more complicated than I'd thought! Edited accordingly.

Comment: @Richard "never the symbiont"? After the last quote I've just added, I'm not so sure any more...

Comment: @randal'thor - My whole life is a lie

Comment: The last quote could just be a descriptor of the type of host, like Riker was a human host for a short while.  Though it would be a bit odd given who is talking to who.

Comment: FWIW, I was assuming that "become a Trill host" meant "become the host part of a joined Trill" (using "Trill" to mean "joined Trill"), not "become the host for a Trill symbiont" (using "Trill" to mean "Trill symbiont"). But I could be wrong.